# Data format of excel changing when uploading to server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oledb, xls, xlsx

I'm developing a website in .Net using OleDb to open an .xlsx file and processing it.
The dates in this file changes the format when the program reads the file. From pt-BR to English.
Is there anything I can set to make sure the date gets read in pt-BR format.

Comment: Set culture on your app thread to pt-BR

Comment: You will likely need to read the Excel values as text and then parse the values based on your culture before using them.  This is done by setting the Extended Property IMEX=1 assuming the registry contains the setting ImportMixedTypes=Text.